# Error Using Decimal And Bool

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my syntax below I get an error of

> An exception of type **'System.FormatException'** occured in **mscorlib.dll** but 
> was not handled in ther user code
>   Additional Information: Input string was not in a correct format

And the value being passed that throws the error is 9.7000 
And this is my syntax - I have a comment above the line that throws an error

```
private void calculate()
{
    var qtys = val(dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Text) + "|" + val(dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text) + "|" + val(dropdownlist2.SelectedItem.Text) ;
    var totalitems = dropdownitem.SelectedItem.Text + "|" + dropdownitem1.SelectedItem.Text + "|" + dropdownitem2.SelectedItem.Text + "|" + dropdownitem3.SelectedItem.Text;
    var amounts = dropdownamt.SelectedItem.Value + "|" + dropdownamt1.SelectedItem.Value + "|" + dropdownamt2.SelectedItem.Value + "|" + dropdownamt3.SelectedItem.Value;  
    var totalitems = itemInfo.Split('|');
    var qtys = qty.Split('|');
    var amounts = amount.Split('|');

    for (int i = 0; i < totalitems.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (totalitems[i] != "" && qtys[i] != "" && qtys[i] != "0")
        {
            TotalPrice += Math.Round(val(amounts[i]), 2);
            TotalTax +=  Math.Round(val(amounts[i]) * Convert.ToDecimal(0.07), 2);
        }
    }
}   


private decimal val(string p)
{
    if (p == null)
        return 0;
    else if (p == "")
        return 0;
    //The value of p = 9.7000
    return Convert.ToInt16(p);
}
```

Comment: `Int16` != `decimal`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to return a `decimal` but calling `Convert.ToInt16` try `Convert.ToDecimal`

Also I would recommend using decimal.TryParse rather than calling Convert directly with some code like this:

```
public decimal convert(string p)
{
    decimal result;
    if(decimal.TryParse(p, out result))
        return result;
    else 
        return 0;
}
```